# How to transform the data using $if $else condition mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, conditional-statements

How to transform the data using $if $else condition MongoDB

[mongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MTtgSG8TsVS)

When no data we get I want to setup have an object

```
record: [
    {
      "text": "No Found",
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Please post the sample data and code in the question.  When mongoplayground does their next wipe, all of that will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your query is attempting to match documents where the embedded `History.user_id` array contains a specific value, and the `date` field is greater than the `History.date` field.  You don't need `$cond'/`$if`for that, you can use`$and`

```
db.main.aggregate([
  {$lookup: {
      from: "history",
      localField: "history_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "History"
  }},
  {$unwind: "$History"},
  {"$match": {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {$in: [
              "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5763",
              "$History.user_id"
          ]},
          {$gt: [
              "$date",
              "$History.date"
          ]}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Yes I was using $and and $eq that doesn't help me how to use ? https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ph8UTosdspZ

Comment: that mean condition should match ID should be in array and should also match $history_id from both collection

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `$cond`?  If you want that to determine the result of the match, you should probably make the `else ` be `false` instead of `{}`

Comment: I am sorrry for confusion the above question is fixed by myself. This is other question should I create new question ? just wanted to use one more condition here if $history user is in array and specified value match with $history's user_id it should also check history collection history_id should be match with main collection history_id

Answer (score 0):

**You Can Follow The Code**

```
db.project.aggregate([

    {
        $project:{
            title:1,

            "author.middle":{
            $cond:{

                if:{$eq:["","$author.middle"]},
                then:"$$REMOVE",
                else:"$author.middle"
            }

            }
        }
    }

])
```